# Images and styles won't load when HTML is opened through the file system rather than through localhost webserver

Tags: html, web-development, css

I'm trying to translate a tutorial of a software. The tutorial is all in HTML, with CSS and some javascript. I'm noob in web development, so I'm a little lost.

The problem is: I found the source-code but when I open the html documents with a browser I can see only the raw pages, without the styles. Different from when I open the tutorial directly from the software.

The URL shown in the address bar is also different.
When I open the index.html document in the browser I see this path:

file:///C:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/LEGO%20Software/LEGO%20MINDSTORMS%20EV3%20Home%20Edition/Resources/EditorHelp/Retail/en-US/index.html

and the page shown is this

[image: raw page]

And when I open the tutorial directly from the software the path is:

http://localhost:58401/localizedMapping_B90BDB05-F70E-4B0B-8CEA-031DCF197215/en-US/editor/

and the page shown is this

[image]

Does Anyone know how can I edit the html documents to see their content directly from the browser with the styles like the second image?

Comment: Files such as CSS and JavaScript might need to be run from an HTTP server, so download a web server like Apache, or you can just use IIS on Windows, place all the files under its public docs directory (e.g., _/htdocs_ for Apache), and then navigate to the URL of the HTML file instead of opening the local file directly with the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly, lego mindstorms is caching the files to improve performance. If you quit the software, make your edits, and then restart the software are your edits reflected?

In addition, you will find your browser's developer tools very useful. Just right click and then select "Inspect Element". Then select whatever tab has "console" in it's name. You should see multiple errors. Can you post them here?

Answer (score 1):

in the `<head>` section of your code search for a line including a file ending `.css` - there may be several. Copy these files to the same folder as the code. 
These files are the stylesheets that set the webpage's colors, fonts, etc.

You should also check for any other files linked to in the `<head>` section - especially javascript (`.js`) files since you will need them too.

CSS files can be edited in whatever source code editor you use for HTML.